# Express res.render not working after redirecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I'm using ajax to make a PUT http request to my server. I handle the request in `/contact/:id'` and then redirect to `'/contacts'`.

However, after redirecting, the view `contacts/index` don't render, but when I simply go to the browser and access `http://localhost:3000/contacts`, it works perfectly. When I do `console.log(params)` in `/contacts` route, they are correct as I expected to be.

Thanks in advance!

app.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var load = require('consign');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: 'ntalk',
     resave: false,
     saveUninitialized: true}));


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: true
}));

app.use('/public', express.static('public'));


app.listen(3000, function(){
     console.log("Running");
});

// Routes

app.post('/enter', function(req,res){
     var name = req.body.user.name;
     var email = req.body.user.email;

     if(name && email){
          var user = req.body.user;
          usuario['contacts'] = [];
          req.session.user = user;
          res.redirect('/contacts');
     }
     else{
          res.redirect('/');
     }
});

app.get('/contacts', function(req,res){
     var user = req.session.user;
     var contacts = user.contacts;
     var params = {
          user: user,
          contacts: contacts
     };
     console.log(params);
     res.render('contacts/index', params);
});

app.put('/contact/:id', function(req,res){
     var user = req.session.user;
     var contacts = req.body.contact;
     var id = req.params.id;
     user.contacts[id] = contact;
     res.redirect(303, '/contacts');
});
```

ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#editForm").submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();

          var data = {
               contact: {
                    name: $("#name").val(),
                    email: $("#email").val()
               }
          };

          $.ajax({
               type: 'PUT',
               url: '/contact/' + $("input:first").val(),
               data: data,
               success: function(){
                    console.log("Edited");
               }
          });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the frontend redirect:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: '/contact/' + $("input:first").val(),
    data: data,
    success: function(){
      console.log("Edited");
      location = '/contacts'; //this is the redirect
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you realize that a redirect on an ajax call doesn't cause the browser to do anything?  It's just a 303 response to your ajax call.  It's up to your ajax code to do something with the redirect response if you want.

If you want the browser page to change, then your code that gets the response from the `PUT` can grab the redirected URL from the ajax response and set `window.location` to cause the browser page to actually change.

Comment: @PedroAugusto - Do you understand why your server-side redirect was not doing anything?  My answer attempted to explain that to you so you'd understand what was going on and tell you how to do the redirect client-side.

Comment: Yes. I got it. Now I understand why it wasn't working. Thanks for the explanation